# How do I check if a user is in a group or another group

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm making an API using django and I want to check whether the user is in a group A or a group B using `request.user.groups.filter()` method but it does not seem to work. I want to be able to pass more than just one group through the `name` parameter to check if they are indeed in group A or group B.

I've tried the following:

```
if request.user.groups.filter(name="A") or request.user.groups.filter(name="B"):
   do stuff
```

I've also tried:

```
if request.user.groups.filter(name="A" or "B"):
   do stuff
```

But I seem to be getting no luck and all I'm getting is that I need to be in group A to access the content when I want it to check whether I'm in A or B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `in`:

```py
if request.user.groups.filter(name__in=["A", "B"]):
```

Or:

```py
if request.user.groups.filter(name__in="AB"):
```

I prefer the `list` version because I think it conveys the intent better than the `str` version without going to the documentation. Of course, the `str` version treats each character as a separate element, so if you have a group name like `"Some Group"`, the `str` version won't work.

[Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#in):

> In a given iterable; often a list, tuple, or queryset. It’s not a common use case, but strings (being iterables) are accepted.
>
> Examples:
>
> Entry.objects.filter(id__in=[1, 3, 4])
>
> Entry.objects.filter(headline__in="abc")
>
> SQL equivalents:
>
> SELECT ... WHERE id IN (1, 3, 4);
>
> SELECT ... WHERE headline IN ('a', 'b', 'c');